# Smallest subset of $\{1,2,...,4n\}$ with a certain property

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

**Fact 1**: Let $A\subseteq\{1,2,...,2n\}$. If $n+1\leq |A|$, then there exists 2 elements $a,b\in A$ such that $a+b=2n+1$.

**Proof**: This can be shown by writing $\{1,2,...,2n\}$ as the union of $n$ disjoint sets $\{i,2n+1-i\}$ where $1\leq i\leq n$. Since $n+1\leq|A|$, we know that $|A\cap \{i,2n+1-i\}|=2$ for some $i\in\{1,2,..,n\}$. Now we're done because $i+2n+1-i=2n+1$.

One also knows that the bound of fact 1 is sharp because $\{1,2,...,n\}$ does not have 2 elements which add up to $2n+1$.

**Definition**: Let $f(n)$ be the smallest number such that:
$$\forall A\subseteq\{1,2,...,4n\}[|A|>f(n)\rightarrow \exists a,b,c,d\in A [a+b+c+d=2(4n+1)] ]$$

**Question**: What are good upper bounds on $f(n)$ ?

**Fact 2:** $f(n)\leq 3n+1$

**Proof**: We repeat the idea of the proof of fact 1. Let $A\subseteq\{1,2,...,4n\},|A|\geq 3n+1$. It can be shown that $\{1,2,...,4n\}$ can be written as the union of disjoint sets:
$$\{1,2,...,4n\}=\cup_{i=1}^{n}\{i,2n+1-i,2n+i,4n+1-i\}$$
(It can also be shown that $\land_{i=1}^n[i,2n+1-i,2n+i,4n+1-i \,are\, distinct\,]$ )
Since $|A|\geq 3n+1$, we know that $|A\cap\{i,2n+1-i,2n+i,4n+1-i\}|=4$ for some $i\in\{1,2,...,n\}$. Now we are done because:  $$i+2n+1-i+2n+i+4n+1-i=2(4n+1)$$
Thus $f(n)\leq 3n+1$.

Unlike fact 1, I am not sure if the bound of fact 2 is sharp. I think there might be more clever ways of using the pigeon hole principle to obtain better upper bounds on $f(n)$.
**Question**: Are there better bounds for $f(n)$ other than those given by fact 2 ?

***My main intrest is about seeing the more clever ways of using the pigeon -hole principle being applied to this problem and not the problem itself.***

Thank you

Comment: Are $a,b,c,d$ supposed to be different or are repetitions allowed?

Comment: repitions are allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(n)=2n+1$.  We write $[1,4n]$ as the disjoint union of $2n$ pairs $\{i,4n+1-i\}$.  If $|A|>f(n)$, then at least two pairs must have both of their elements in $A$; the sum of those four elements is $8n+2$.  On the other hand, let $A=[1,2n+1]$.  The four largest elements from $A$ sum to $8n-2$, so no four elements from $A$ sum to $8n+2$.

Edit: fixed typo.

Comment: OK. This is good. However, you seem to assume implicitly that $a,b,c,d$ must be distinct. But, I think think your idea could be slightly modified to deal with this problem

Comment: In case repetitions are not allowed, I think you wanted to write $f(n)=2n+2$.

Comment: $|A|>2n+1$ implies $|A|\ge 2n+2$.  If $a,b,c,d$ need not be distinct, then $2n\le f(n) \le 2n+1$, where now $A=[1,2n]$ is used for the lower bound.